# How to deal with poor HTML5 video performance in Chrome?

Tags: html, video

Over a year ago we added an [video page](http://www.remobjects.com/tv/) on our site. At the time OGV wasn't very good, and there was no good WebM encoders available, so we decided to use HTML5 and h.264 for webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.) and then fallback to Flash for other browsers (using the same h.264 source file.)

This has been working great for a while. Recently (month or two maybe, so over multiple Chrome versions - currently Version 24.0.1312.52 m) we discovered Chrome really lagging on the playback. We thought it was a server issue, so we upgraded the server, and it is still behaving the same. I remembered reading that Google wanted to drop h.264 and move everyone to WebM, and thought this performance was part of that. We converted some videos to WebM and tested them with Chrome and they lag just as bad. Same video (WebM) streams beautifully in FireFox, and the MP4 streams great in FireFox via the Flash plug in.

I went to YouTube and turned on the HTML5 video support, and found the videos to lag in Chrome too (when running at HD) while they play fine in Flash mode. (Even when HTML5 is enabled, some videos still play via Flash.)

Tested on both Windows 8 and Mountain Lion.

I've talked to co-workers and they are seeing the same issues. So it isn't just me. So my question is:

1. Is this an issue with our video encoding?
2. Is it a bug with Chrome?
3. Or is it just localized to us?
4. Is there a way to deal with this besides switching back to Flash?

Comment: I see this too, but only noticeable at larger video sizes. To be honest I had put this down to the lack-of power on my test machine - but maybe not?!

Comment: @w3d A year ago the performance was good. I thought I was having machine issues too, or that I changed the encoding, but even old videos play the same.

Comment: Can you share a test video, encoded the same as your content but exhibiting the same behavior? Does it behave the same on OSX and Windows? Is it a large framesize, or a high framerate? Do you have any Chrome plugins/extensions that may be skewing the results

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Same on OSX and Windows - I've tried it with all Chrome extensions disabled. . You can download the [MP4 video from here](http://www.remobjects.com/tv/oxygene.aspx?video=oxygene-19-fixit-reloaded). It is 720p.

Comment: Hey Jim, tried the video (and others on the site) from home in Chrome on OSX and they seem fine, even seeking way ahead of the buffer is fine. what are you experiencing by way of "lag"? They are fine in both the small and the large modes (fun to see Pascal again after all these years!). How does it behave through an event logger like https://gist.github.com/3718414?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Thanks for checking it. That is interesting. Glad it is working for you. The playback I get is it starts buffering, I start playing, and then like 2 seconds in it just lags out and stops playing not to recover. The playhead is still within the pre-buffered amount too.

Comment: @JimMcKeeth I guess you're still having this issue. I use Google Chrome for my digital signage suite and I've had tons of issues with H.264. Try enabling Google Chrome 'disable hardware acceleration when rendering H.264' flag (worked for me - I'm using Projekktor for HTML5 video handling).

Comment: @JorgeAntonioDíaz-Benito Where is the 'disable hardware acceleration when rendering H.264' flag enabled?

Comment: @JimMcKeeth See my answer (I think I can't include images in comments, that's why I answered).

Comment: @JorgeAntonioDíaz-Benito Ok about the hardware acceleration flag what about the users that visit the site and have no idea about the flag, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @BillK Check my new reply to the question.

Comment: Hmm, don't see that in my Chrome. However some friends complained about HTML5 the other day.

Comment: Isn't there a way to delay showing video. Can't one download ahead and display with a 10 minute delay? Thus watching off your harddisk with speed...

Comment: 2020 and it still isn't working great

Answer (score 18):

[image: HW-acc video decode]

This is the flag I mean. If the flag is **disabled**, the browser tries to use hw-accelerated video decoding, which I can grant provokes wrong and slow video renderization in some devices. If **enabled**, hw-accelerated video decode is never used, but the above mentioned problems disappear. It theorically increases decoding time in devices actually able to use such acceleration, but I've been working around this field for almost a year and I still didn't realize any difference in that matter. Still didn't get to know how to identify if a device will behave properly (the availability of this feature doesn't seem to grant its proper behavior) with such acceleration without testing, though.

Comment: This should be the answer. Some devices have hardware-decode built in; others do not. (but the majority of devices should have a video-decode, (NOT video) chip built in) When this is enabled, Chrome tries to find the chip while subsequently decoding the video through software. In my tests, this caused slight lag but maybe because I was running on VM. Again, try and test it on your device - it should have the decode chip!~

Comment: Turning on this flag means worse battery life when laptop users play your videos. All modern gear supports hardware decoding of video, not just for smoothness but also to use less battery. If Google Chrome has a problem, that a competing browser on same pc does not, then please complain to Google.