# Poor performance in Chrome running HTML5 Video

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I'm a little confused by this one. A similar question was posted here:

[How to deal with poor HTML5 video performance in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411977/how-to-deal-with-poor-html5-video-performance-in-chrome)

but no satisfactory resolution seems to have come of it.

The long and short of it is that the HTML5 video element has a very poor performance in Chrome. Every other browser I've tried (IE9/10, Opera, Firefox, Safari, Safari iOS) runs absolutely fine but Chrome (for Windows) buffers very slowly and occasionally stops buffering altogether. It seems to ignore the preload attribute, although according to this article:

http://oddlystudios.com/blog/html5-video-problems-in-chrome/

it DOES preload, just limits itself at a couple of MB. This is *definitely* a recent thing, probably only affecting recent versions (I'm on 26.0.1410.64 m) and it's not only affecting my projects but also other sites including YouTube. It seems to be irrespective of file format, and only seems to affect longer videos (those of 5 minutes and above).

I guess my question is, has anybody else come across this phenomenon? If so, how do you combat it? In the other thread disabling the hardware acceleration for H.264 was suggested, but not only does this not work for me, but it's impractical from a development standpoint.

Comment: What OS (on OSX my Chrome is 26.0.1510.65) and video in general seems okay though I have seen what you mention with youTube quite often. `preload="auto"` in Chrome appears to not be agressive enough in current builds :(

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I've been running Windows 7 at work (as have my colleagues) and also 8 on my home computer - there are subtle differences between the Windows/OSX versions of Chrome so it could well be limited to Windows builds. `preload="auto"` seems to do relatively little, unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe you should just clear your Chrome's browser cache, cookies, history etc. HTML5 videos have always played very well on Chrome on my PC with Windows 8 and also OSX. And you could always try adding another video source to your video tag and see if it's maybe because your video file is very big.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Chrome itself preload just few of MB's among its entire video. The only approach taken by me was, to show loading progress bar while we load the entire video at background. once fully loaded the video, remove the loading layer and show the video to play ahead.